# Калькулятор с одним input

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Суть в том, что калькулятор с одним input. Например, вводим первое число, выбираем операцию,очищается input.Вводим в этот же input 2ое число кликаем на ровно и в этом же input'е получаем ответ. Помогите додумать код.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
 <Style>
 </Style>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function calc(){
 var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
 var op = document.getElementById("opr").value

 if(op == "+"){
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
  document.getElementById('input').value = num1+num2;
 }
 if(op === "-"){
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
  document.getElementById('input').value = num1-num2;
 }
 if(op === "x"){
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
  document.getElementById('input').value = num1*num2;
 }
 if(op === "/"){
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
  document.getElementById('input').value = num1/num2;
 }
 if(op === "%"){
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input").value)
  document.getElementById('input').value = num1%num2;
 }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
  Calculator
 </h1>
  <input type = "text" id = "input">
    <select id = "opr">
      <option value = "+">+</option>
      <option value = "-">-</option>
      <option value = "x">x</option>
      <option value = "/">/</option>
      <option value = "%">%</option>
  </select>
 <input type = "Button" value = "=" onclick="calc();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: какой то нелогичный и неправильный калькулятор

Comment: задание такое дано

Comment: ааа, ну тогда доберусь до компа и напишу

Comment: Было бы здорово, с утра уже сижу и не получается логично всё выстроить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужны две функции: одна запомнит первый операнд и операцию, тогда можно будет ввести второй операнд; вторая непосредственно все подсчитает.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // выбрали операцию
  document.querySelector('#opr').addEventListener('change', save);
  // считаем
  document.querySelector('#result').addEventListener('click', calc);
});
var firstArg = 0;
var operationSaved = '';
// запоминаем операцию и первый операнд
function save() {
    var input = document.querySelector("#input");
    var operation = this.value;
    if(operation) {
      firstArgSaved = parseFloat(input.value);
      input.value = '';
      operationSaved = this.value;
    }
}
function calc(){
  var input = document.querySelector("#input");
  var secondArg = parseFloat(input.value);
  var result;
  if(operationSaved) {
    switch(operationSaved) {
      case '+':
        result = firstArgSaved + secondArg;
      break;
      case '-':
        result = firstArgSaved - secondArg;
      break;
      case 'x':
        result = firstArgSaved * secondArg;
      break;
      case '/':
        result = firstArgSaved / secondArg;
      break;
      case '%':
        result = firstArgSaved % secondArg;
      break;
    }
    input.value = result;
    // сброс операции для следующего срабатывания save
    document.querySelector('#opr').value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
  <input type="text" id="input">
    <select id="opr">
      <option value=""> </option>
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
      <option value="%">%</option>
  </select>
 <input id="result" type="button" value="=" />
```

Comment: а как чистить input после ввода первого числа и выбора операции? чтобы при вводе 2ого числа не нужно было вручную очищать input?

Comment: @Jevgewa поправил.